# Was the small Desargues Theorem known to ancient Greeks?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, incidence-geometry

My question concerns the classical Desargues Theorem and its simplest version

> **The small Desargues Theorem:** Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three distinct parallel lines and $a,a'\in A$, $b,b'\in B$, $c,c'\in C$, be points such that $ab\parallel a'b'$ and $bc\parallel b'c'$. Then $ac\parallel a'c'$.

The small Desargues Theorem does not involve any Projective Geometry, so could have been known to ancient geometers (Thales, Euclides, Proclus, Pappus etc.).

> **Question.** Is there any evidence that the small Desargues Theorem was known to ancient Greeks?

Comment: May be more appropriate on the [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BrianHopkins Thank you for the suggestion. I have copied my question there: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/was-the-small-desargues-theorem-known-to-ancient-greeks

Comment: In a weird coincidence, I was wondering this exact question and was about to ask it.  I feel like it must have been known to the ancient Greeks.

Comment: @arsmath At the moment I am writing a textbook in Foundations of Geometry. So, I asked this question hoping to rename the small Desargue Theorem by some more ancient name, reserving the name "Desargues" for the full Desargues Theorem.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Since the theorem is necessary to prove that vector addition works, maybe you can find it in an old-fashioned geometry book that starts synthetically, and then introduces vectors.

Comment: @arsmath Yes, I have already found it in the "old-fashioned" geometry book of Harntshorne: https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/aconstant/Alg2/Bib/Hartshorne_Projective.pdf And the synthetic proof is very simple, certainly available to Euclid, see my comment to Mikail Katz answer.

Comment: When you ask "Is it true or not?", it reads to me sort of like you are asking whether or not the theorem is true (which of course it is, and you know it is).  Would you be amenable to changing the wording to "Was it?" or "Was it known?"  (Or of course you could just delete that sentence, since it is asked explicitly in the following demarcated text.)

Comment: By "old-fashioned" I mean from the 19th or early 20th century.  I would call the Hartshorne book "modern" incidence geometry, since he's already thinking in terms of general fields.

Comment: The attempt to close this post is unreasonable.  Maybe we should look into MO accepting an official guideline that whatever research mathematicians are interested in, is considered par for the course at MO.  @TarasBanakh

Comment: This question would *not* do better at the HSM site because answering it requires a level of mathematical expertise not possessed by most users there.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I think it deserves to be stated explicitly:

I don't know if the Greeks *knew* this result, but lest there be any doubt that the Greeks *could* have proved it, here is a proof using essentially only proposition 34 in book I of Euclid's *Elements*, which states that

> two opposite sides of a parallelogram are equal to one another

(a “parallelogram” here means a quadrilateral whose opposite sides are parallel, and “equal” means having equal length).

In the present situation, $aa'b'b$ is a parallelogram and $bb'c'c$ is a parallelogram, and our goal is to show that $aa'c'c$ is.

Now the quoted proposition I.34 implies that $aa' = bb'$ and that $bb' = cc'$ as distances, so (as things equal to a third are equal to each other, this is Euclid's first “axiom”) $aa' = cc'$.  Furthermore, the line $A=(aa')$ and $B=(bb')$ are parallel, and so are the lines $B=(bb')$ and $C=(cc')$, so $A$ and $C$ are parallel (this is proposition I.30 in Euclid).  Now $aa'c'c$ has the two opposite sides $aa'$ and $cc'$ that are parallel and of equal length, so by the converse of the aforementioned proposition, $aa'c'c$ is a parallelogram.

OK, I couldn't find the converse of I.34 explicitly in Euclid, but it is easy to deduce it from I.34 itself: let $c^*$ be the point such that $aa'c^*c$ is a parallelogram (i.e., the intersection of the line $C$ with the parallel to $(ac)$ through $a'$), applying I.34 again we see that $cc^*=aa'$ and we have noted that $cc'=aa'$, so $cc^* = cc'$ and since they are on the same line¹, $c'=c^*$.  (I suspect that the Greeks would have done this in a different way, but I have absolutely no doubt that the converse of I.34 was clear to them.)

1. Astute readers will note that $c^*$ could conceivably be on the other side of $c$ from $c'$ from what I said, but this kind of omissions, merely supported by a figure, abound in Euclid.  Pretty much the same reasoning is in I.35 (except that areas are used instead of distances).

**Addendum:** To summarize, I am tempted to say that the result being asked about (which again is a *particular affine form* of what is often known as the “little Desargues” theorem) is pretty much Euclid's proposition I.34: basically, we are to show that $\vec{aa'} = \vec{bb'}$ and $\vec{bb'} = \vec{cc'}$ implies $\vec{aa'} = \vec{cc'}$ (where “$\vec{xx'} = \vec{yy'}$” means by definition “$xx'y'y$ is a parallelogram”), and even though Euclid didn't know about vectors, he knew about lengths and parallels, and the above proof states that the lengths and directions are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also have a simple (and standard synthetic)  proof of the small Desargues Theorem using Proposition 15 and 16 from the Euclid's book XI (go out to the 3-d dimension and then project back).

Comment: There's a dichotomy between the two proofs, which was basically noted by Hilbert.  You can prove the theorem by using congruences or by passing to 3D.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I asked this question hoping to find some appropriate name that can be legally used for naming affine spaces satisfying the small Desargues Theorem. Now I have learned that in Projective Geometry, projective planes satisfying the projective analog of the small Desargues Theorem are called *[Moufang planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_plane)*, which was also mentioned in the comment of @Gro-Tsen. So, it is logical to call affine planes satisfying the small Desargues Theorem *Moufang affine planes.* Is such a choice of terminology sufficiently justified, or there is a better one?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this is a perfectly sensible terminology (at least if I am correct in my belief that this is precisely the structure of a projective Moufang plane minus a line qualified as “line at infinity”). I decline to comment, however, on whether “Moufang affine plane” or “affine Moufang plane” is preferable (or whether the adjectives commute).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen The adjectives "Moufang" and "affine" do not commute because I have a notion of an affine space (an incidence geometry in which the Playfair axiom of Parallel holds) and "Moufang" is a partial case of affine spaces in which the small Desargues Theorem holds. So, all affine spaces of dimension $\ge 3$ are Desarguesian and Moufang and some affine spaces of dimension 2 (i.e., affine planes) are Moufang, but there are also non-Moufang planes, for example, the Moulton plane, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moulton_plane

Answer (score -1):

Your "small Desargues theorem" is weaker than the full Desargues theorem (as pointed out by Gro-Tsen in a [*comment*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450764/was-the-small-desargues-theorem-known-to-ancient-greeks#comment1165599_450933)).  Thus the small Desargues theorem cannot be proved in any given non-Mounfang plane.  So to give a synthetic proof (since they didn't present analytic proofs), the Greeks would have had to go out to 3 dimensions.  I think this makes it unlikely that they would have known the result.

Comment: The theorem as stated by OP is a particular affine form of the [special case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem#The_little_Desargues_theorem) of the Desargues theorem whereby the center of perspectivity lies on the axis of perspectivity. This theorem is known to hold in Moufang planes (e.g., the octonionic projective plane) which may fail to be Desarguian. So it is strictly weaker than the full Desargues theorem.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, thanks, I didn't know that.  So my observation should be limited to non-Moufang planes, is that correct?

Comment: @MikhailKatz But ancient Greeks knew stereometry very well. What is the problem for Greeks to go out the plane to the 3-d dimension?

Comment: @TarasBanakh, Maybe you are right (I only said "unlikely" in my opinion).  What particular result in Greek stereometry do you have in mind?

Comment: The full Desargues theorem is a theorem in Euclidean geometry (though to avoid using projective geometry you have to consider a bunch of cases), so it must follow from the order properties of the reals.  So there's no requirement to pass to 3d to prove the special case here.

Comment: @arsmath, the Greeks did not possess analytic geometry, which was only created in the 17th century by Fermat and Descartes.  As I mentioned in my *answer*, the Greeks could only have provided a synthetic, not an analytic, proof.

Comment: @MikhailKatz The proof of small Desargues Theorem uses only two facts: (1) a plane $\Pi_1$ is parallel to a plane $\Pi_2$ if $\Pi_1$ contains two intersecting lines that are parallel to the plane $\Pi_2$ and (2) intersecting two parallel planes by a third plane, we obtain two parallel lines. Those two results were certainly known to Euclid. More precisely, they are Propositions 15 and 16 in the book XI of Euclid, see http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookXI/bookXI.html

Comment: @TarasBanakh, That's very interesting.  This wasn't clear from your "question" at all.  I think you should include this information.  So are you saying that all the tools were there to provide a synthetic proof?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Exactly! By the way, I think that the modern approach to teaching geometry (from the middle, starting with analytic geometry) is bad and we should return back to Euclid with his axiomatic treatment of geometry, explaining how to  obtain the structure of a vector space from the axioms.  It is not very difficult. It took me only 25 pages with all the details, but gives much better understanding what is going on and why.

Comment: I looked in Hilbert's "Foundations of Geometry", and he gives a proof entirely in the plane.  He first proves what he calls "Pascal's theorem" though I think it's just a special case of Pappus' theorem using the axioms of congruence, and then proves a special case of Desargues from that.

Comment: @arsmath This is an important result (that the small Desargues Theorem holds in 2-dimensional Euclidean Geometry), which allowed Hilbert to move forward with coordinates.

Comment: @arsmath, I would think that both Hartshorne and Hilbert would classify as "modern".  On the other hand, I think we already have two convincing arguments on this page that a proof was within the reach of the Greeks.  I am surprised by what you say about Pascal.  I think Pascal is a generalisation of Pappus (namely, when the conic degenerates to a pair of intersecting lines) rather than vice versa, but maybe I am missing some subtle point.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yes, Pascal is a generalization of Pappus. And Pappus Axiom implies the commutativity of the coordinate skew-field. It is interesting why Hilbert refers to Pascal and not to Pappus.

Comment: Hilbert's book is probably the transition point.  He's trying to determine the logical interdependence between the axioms of Euclidean geometry, and observes the particular importance of Desargues theorem for coordinates, but it's not the main point of his book.  He calls Pappus' theorem "Pascal's theorem" for some reason.

Comment: Apollonius used analytic geometry.

Comment: @BenWieland, if you mention this to Michael Fried or Unguru, they'll have a fit :-)  According to which historian?

Comment: I don't care what historians say. I care what Apollonius does.

Comment: @BenWieland, I am interested in understanding Apollonius, but your claim is a novel one.  Do you have some details?  Where did he allegedly use analytic geometry?  Note that some historians of math are certainly mathematically competent: van der Waerden, Freudenthal, and others.